# Can I convert an existing LVM VG to a stripe (RAID0 eq)?

Tags: lvm, raid

I have an existing LVM volume group of 3 disks (ext4), with 4 logical volumes. Not quite ready for the leap to a nextgen FS, I  would like to balance the load on the disks. I have seen you can create VG's with striping (RAID0 equivalent), but I would like to convert the existing one. Can this be done?

Comment: I trust you know this already, but please be aware that a RAID0-style striping (whether actually RAID 0 or LVM) can potentially leave you without any data at all if even just one of the disks fails. You're effectively reducing your disk statistical time to failure by a considerable amount.

Comment: The accepted answer of the "duplicate" question does NOT work for this question, unless the VG can be shrunk to a single-drive first (assuming disks of roughly the same size).

Comment: Posted with clarification as https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/697251/tool-for-converting-an-existing-multi-disk-lvm-to-be-striped

Answer (score 1):

Don't know how far back this was documented, but in v2.02.183, `man lvconvert` shows:

```
--stripes Number
       Specifies the number of stripes in a striped LV. This is the number of PVs
       (devices) that a striped LV is spread across. Data that appears sequential in
       the LV is spread across multiple devices in units of the stripe size (see
       --stripesize). This does not apply to existing allocated space, only newly
       allocated space can be striped.
```

So, it won't actually *convert* an existing LV to a stripe.  Existing data will be left as is.

Comment: In the edge case that the VG uses only 1/3 or less of the space, there is a solution involving first moving all LVs to a single PV, shrinking the VG and then following https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/348873/convert-a-single-drive-lvm-volume-to-a-striped-volume-across-3-drives

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo lvconvert --stripes 3 vg/lv /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb1 /dev/sdc1
```

Where 2 is the number of stripes, then the logical volume, then the 3 devices to stripe across. RAID 0 has no redundancy.

Comment: Is it really so easy? Can you show your `lvdisplay -am` before and after?

Comment: Doesn't work for me. `lvconvert` does say it can't be used like that.