# Convert a single-drive LVM volume to a striped volume across 3 drives

Tags: storage, lvm

On my server using LVM, I have a simple linear LV on a single drive (PV). Now, I added 2 more (same size) drives (PVs) to the server.

I want to convert my existing linear LV to a striped LV (RAID0 like) across the 3 drives, if possible, online. This would allow me to enhance performance, thanks to the striping. I know it is *theoretically* possible.

I tried many things, like creating a striped mirror of my LV, based on [this website technique](https://www.depesz.com/2015/10/08/converting-logical-volume-so-that-its-striped/), but in my case it is more complicated because I want to keep using the original drive (on the website, it is a migration from a single drive LV to 3 *other* drives).

I am becoming more and more familiar with the `pvmove`, `lvconvert` and other LVM tools but didn't succeed. Please help. :)

If needed, I have very few extra space on another drive (about 5% of my original LV size).

My `lvdisplay -m` is as follows:

```
--- Logical volume ---
LV Path                /dev/vg_space/vol_space
LV Name                vol_space
VG Name                vg_space
LV Status              available
# open                 1
LV Size                260.75 GiB
Current LE             66752
Segments               1
Allocation             inherit
Read ahead sectors     auto
- currently set to     256
Block device           253:0

--- Segments ---
Logical extent 0 to 66751:
  Type                linear       
  Physical volume     /dev/sda5
  Physical extents    0 to 66751
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I finally found a <s>trick</s> way.

**The setup**: Let's say our original drive is `/dev/sda` (PV is `/dev/sda1`) and our two new drives are `/dev/sdb` and `/dev/sdc`. All drives are 100 MB big.

**The idea**: Because all our data can fit on half of `sdb` and `sdc`, we can temporarily put our data there and in the meanwhile, create a striped mirror of our LV across the 3 other halves of the drives. Then, get rid of the original side of the (temporary) mirror and extend our striped LV to full size.

This wonderful piece of art should explain better:

```
original state:

   sda       sdb       sdc
 _______   _______   _______
|       | |       | |       |
|       | |       | |       |
|lv_orig| | empty | | empty |
|       | |       | |       |
|       | |       | |       |
|       | |       | |       |
|       | |       | |       |
|_______| |_______| |_______|


partition sdb & sdc, pvmove, then partition sda:

   sda       sdb       sdc
 _______   _______   _______
|       | |       | |       |
| sda1  | | sdb1  | | sdc1  |
| empty | | empty | | empty |
|_______| |_______| |_______|
|       | |       | |       |
| sda2  | |lv_orig| |lv_orig| <= linear on 2 drives
| empty | |half 1 | |half 2 |
|_______| |_______| |_______|


add sda{1,2,3} to vg, mirror the LV on this in striped mode:

   sda       sdb       sdc
 _______   _______   _______
|lv_orig| |lv_orig| |lv_orig|
|mirror | |mirror | |mirror |  <= striped!
|stripe1| |stripe2| |stripe3|
|_______| |_______| |_______|
|       | |       | |       |
| sda2  | |lv_orig| |lv_orig|
| empty | |half 1 | |half 2 |
|_______| |_______| |_______|



get rid of the sd{b,c}2 side of the mirror:

   sda       sdb       sdc
 _______   _______   _______
|       | |       | |       |
|lv_orig| |lv_orig| |lv_orig|  <= still striped!
|stripe1| |stripe2| |stripe3|
|_______| |_______| |_______|
|       | |       | |       |
| sda2  | | sdb2  | | sdc2  |
| empty | | empty | | empty |
|_______| |_______| |_______|


delete sd{a,b,c}2 partitions to extend sd{a,b,c}1 on the whole disk,
finally, extend the lv:

   sda       sdb       sdc
 _______   _______   _______
|       | |       | |       |
| sda1  | | sdb1  | | sdc1  |
|       | |       | |       |
|lv_orig| |lv_orig| |lv_orig|  <= definitely striped!
|       | |       | |       |
|bigger&| |bigger&| |bigger&|
|striped| |striped| |striped|
|_______| |_______| |_______|
```

**Here is how to proceed :**

*Disclaimer: I wrote this mostly based on memories, please double check the commands (and edit the post if needed!)*

- create the partitions `sdb1` and `sdb2`, respectively 42 and 58 MB,
- same thing for `sdc`,
- `pvcreate /dev/sd{b,c}{1,2}`,
- `vgextend vg_orig /dev/sdb2 /dev/sdc2`,
- `pvmove /dev/sda1` will move all LV data to `sdb2` and `sdc2`,
- `vgreduce vg_orig /dev/sda1` and `pvremove /dev/sda1` will make LVM completely stop using `sda`,
- create a 42 MB partition `/dev/sda1` (erasing the previous one if needed), and `pvcreate /dev/sda1`, `vgextend vg_orig dev/sd{a,b,c}1`,
- `lvconvert --type mirror --mirrors 1 --stripes 3 vg_orig/lv_orig /dev/sd{a,b,c}1` will create a stripped mirror of our original LV volume (what we are looking for!), you can check the details with `lvdisplay -am`,
- the previous command may fail if the total number of extends in the LV is not a multiple of 3, in which case, you can simply add 1 or 2 extend to the LV like this: `lvextend -l +1 vg_orig/lv_orig`,
- with this command, we will get rid of the temporary mirror copy of the data we have in `sdb2` and `sdc2`: `lvconvert --type mirror --mirrors 0 vg_orig/lv_orig /dev/sd{b,c}2`,
- remove the sdX2 partitions we don't need anymore: `vgreduce vg_orig /dev/sd{b,c}2`, `pvremove /dev/sd{b,c}2`,
- now we have a striped version of our original data, we still need to make the `sd{a,b,c}1` partitions bigger, so delete the `sdb2` and `sdc2` partitions and recreate the `sda1`, `sdb1` and `sdc1`, partitions so that they start at the same sector number, but end at a higher sector number (don't be afraid :)),
- `partprobe /dev/sd{a,b,c}1` to refresh the kernel partition table,
- `pvresize /dev/sd{a,b,c}1` to make LVM realize the PVs are bigger,
- `lvextend -l 100%VG vg_orig/lv_orig` to make the LV bigger now,
- `resize2fs vg_orig/lv_orig` if you have an ext filesystem that you want to grow online.

Here you go!

It is pretty confusing to me that a tool like LVM, supposedly made for this kind of operation is not able to do this task easily in a single (or two) command...

Comment: The man page says "In most cases, the mirror type is deprecated and the raid1 type should be used." Is the above a case in which `--type mirror` is not depreciated? If not, might be worthwhile making a request to the developers to keep this feature for use cases like this one.

Comment: Mirror vs. raid1: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/697364/in-what-cases-will-type-mirror-continue-to-be-a-good-choice-is-not-depre

Comment: Replacing `--type mirror` with `type raid1` in above procedure, the mirror is linear over `sda{a,b,c}1`, not striped.

Comment: There may be a little time travel happening here -- just note that this (accepted) answer is just over 5 years old at this point. The deprecation may have happened in that timeframe.

Comment: @JeffSchaller Actually, `raid1` probably never worked in this scenario and `mirror` should still work (it only temporarily was rendered unusable in the CLI), reading on the lvm2 bug tracker and https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/697364/in-what-cases-will-type-mirror-continue-to-be-a-good-choice-is-not-depre

Comment: Hi @JoachimWagner, did you consider the `--type striped` or `raid0` options of `lvconvert`? (regarding the deprecation of the `mirror` type) It's been some time since I dug into this, so, I'm asking not out of knowledge, but out of curiosity ("maybe it works" spirit).

Comment: @Tutor: Yes, I tried and it didn't work as it only applies to new allocations. `mirror` is used here to copy data to the striped set without disrupting users of the volume. If you can accept a downtime you can simple create the striped volume, copy data (filesystem image or individual files), configure your system to use the new volume and then grow it.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is according @Totor diagram,
However, I'd change the second step by creating new file system on new lvm raid0 (on sdb and sdc). Then copy to it with `rsync -avP`. Then create new raid0 with 3 stripes on (sda1, sdb1,sdc1). Then rsync from 2 stripes to 3 stripes, and lvresize/extend.
Takes 2 times copy only.

Comment: I think the Totor version also does only 2 copies in reality but it uses `pvmove` to do it instead of `rsync`. I think it depends on the filesystem which method has higher performance.

Comment: `rsync` would not allow a live, online migration, contrary to `pvmove`. Downtimes would be involved. Although, it would probably be a faster copy if your volume filesystem is not filled much and if you don't have a great number of small file. Otherwise, `pvmove` would probably be faster (block level copy).

Comment: To all of comments, converting to raid0 with lvm is very cumbersome process (first you make raid1, then raid5_n, and only then convert to raid0). With my method it's possible to convert 1 drive with info to raid0 just adding 1 extra drive! Raid5_n requires 2 extra disks.