# In what case(s) will `--type mirror` continue to be a good choice / is not deprecated?

Tags: lvm, storage

The man page of `lvcreate` says that the LV type `mirror` is legacy and `lvconvert` says "In most cases, the mirror type is deprecated and the raid1 type  should be used.  They are both implementations of mirroring."

What would be cases in which `--type mirror` is *not* deprecated?

I came across `--type mirror` in the procedure in the accepted answer of
[Convert a single-drive LVM volume to a striped volume across 3 drives](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/348873/convert-a-single-drive-lvm-volume-to-a-striped-volume-across-3-drives) and wonder would `--type raid1` also work there?

Avery Payne's answer on https://serverfault.com/questions/97845/lvm-mirroring-vs-raid1 suggests a historic difference in that `mirror` is used for moving LVs around and are usually only used temporarily, while `raid1` is for permanent protection of data. The man page of `pvmove` also mentions that a temporary mirror LV is created to move data.

Related:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/379440/whats-the-difference-between-mirror-and-raid1-in-lvm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comments on [the `global/mirror_segtype_default` setting](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=lvm2.git;a=blob;f=conf/example.conf.in;h=94f7a23fdb119d852e620bb4f3aab6939ff31eb7;hb=HEAD#l1065) in the example configuration file describe the differences between the two types:

> mirror
> The original RAID1 implementation from LVM/DM. It is
> characterized by a flexible log solution (core, disk, mirrored),
> and by the necessity to block I/O while handling a failure.
> There is an inherent race in the dmeventd failure handling logic
> with snapshots of devices using this type of RAID1 that in the
> worst case could cause a deadlock. (Also see
> devices/ignore_lvm_mirrors.)
>
> raid1
> This is a newer RAID1 implementation using the MD RAID1
> personality through device-mapper. It is characterized by a
> lack of log options. (A log is always allocated for every
> device and they are placed on the same device as the image,
> so no separate devices are required.) This mirror
> implementation does not require I/O to be blocked while
> handling a failure. This mirror implementation is not
> cluster-aware and cannot be used in a shared (active/active)
> fashion in a cluster.

Further down, a comment on `global/support_mirrored_mirror_log` might also explain in which circumstances `mirror` can be used:

> This type is deprecated to create or convert to but can
> be enabled to test that activation of existing mirrored
> logs and conversion to disk/core works.

That is to say, that supporting type `mirror` is at least useful to allow access to old setups using it. (But that doesn’t justify allowing `lvconvert` to convert *to* type `mirror`.)

Red Hat (which drives most of the LVM development work) [has documented that support for type `mirror` will be removed at some point from RHEL](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/8.4_release_notes/deprecated_functionality#deprecated-functionality_file-systems-and-storage), but that hasn’t happened yet. (This isn’t *necessarily* correlated with removal of the feature in the LVM project and kernel themselves.)

Comment: Does this mean that there is no plan to remove support for `--type mirror` and "deprecated" here really means "discouraged"?

Comment: "To test [it] works" doesn't sound like a good reason to keep a feature if it is otherwise superfluous. Is it maybe to support accessing old storage systems?

Comment: I’m not familiar with the LVM developers’ plans; I’m not aware of an announced *removal* of support for the `mirror` type.

Comment: The specific setting which the comment applies to is only included for test use; but the fact that a test is being kept to ensure that old features work implies that the overall feature is kept so that old setups can still be accessed.

Comment: Current `pvmove` of lvm2 tools v2.03.15 still seems to use `mirror`, at least that's the type `lvdisplay -m -a` shows while `pvmove` is doing its work.

Comment: @JoachimWagner "deprecated" always means "discouraged" but specifically that it will not be removed or prohibited.

Comment: `lvconvert --type raid1 --mirrors 1 --stripes 3 testvg/mylv /dev/vd[bcd]1` ignores `stripes` and produces a linear mirror across the 3 PVs, so `--type mirror` seems to be needed in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/348873/convert-a-single-drive-lvm-volume-to-a-striped-volume-across-3-drives

Comment: Feature request to keep `mirror`: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2070211

Comment: @jesse_b https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8111774/deprecated-meaning says it "may indicate that the feature will be removed in the future" and I've often seen features disappearing a few releases later. Definitely not a pledge for continued long-term support.

Comment: @JoachimWagner Sure deprecation can be a step before removal but nothing about deprecation specifically means eventually to be removed.  In fact once something is removed it can no longer be called deprecated.  And there is a long list of features on *nix operating systems that have been deprecated for decades and still exist, and likely will never be removed.