# Adding a 3rd device to 2-striped LVM to make 3-striped volume on Linux

Tags: linux, lvm, storage

Currently I have single 2TB harddrive without LVM, very soon will add a 2nd one making 2-striped volume. So I'm trying to plan for the future expansion where I'll need to add a 3rd  one.
Hence the problem to solve:
2 physical drives making a 2-striped LVM volume, filled with data to the fullest;
1 empty physical drive;
need to "merge" the 3 to make a 3-striped volume.

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/349041/103095) answer, in general, recommends an approach to create a 3-striped volume on the new space and copy the existing data to it, then empty the original storage, and then reoccupy all the space.
But that approach doesn't seem usable in setups where newly added space is smaller than the source. That is, you can copy 2 TB data to a new 2+2 TB empty location, but obviously 4TB on the contrary won't fit into 2TB.

To this moment I've been experimenting in a virtual machine:

1. Split the new single "harddrive" into 3 physical volumes;
2. Make an LVM volume with them, with 3 stripes;
3. Move the data there (only 50% of it will fit in);
4. Shrink the PV and LV on the original disks after freeing space;
5. Move PVs one by one from the 3rd drive to the original drives and extend to gradually reoccupy the freed space, and as a result have the LVM volume with 3 PVs of the 3 drives.

But that can't be done without shrinking the LVM on the original drives. Which doesn't look doable because all the space looks allocated even after I removed a significant part of data.

Searching only gives answers about non-striped volumes or for cases when you have extra space to temporarily store all the data.
**Is there some way to safely shrink a *striped* LVM volume?**
**Or maybe there is some other way to do the task of the topic, without additional storage except the mentioned 3 drives?**

```
#pvs
PV         VG   Fmt  Attr PSize    PFree
  /dev/vdb1  lv_s lvm2 a--  1020.00m    0 
  /dev/vdc1  lv_s lvm2 a--  1020.00m    0 
  /dev/vdd1  lt_t lvm2 a--   336.00m    0 
  /dev/vdd2  lt_t lvm2 a--   336.00m    0 
  /dev/vdd3  lt_t lvm2 a--   336.00m    0

#vgs
VG   #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize    VFree
lt_t   3   1   0 wz--n- 1008.00m    0 
lv_s   2   1   0 wz--n-    1.99g    0
```

Ignore the small sizes, it's just a sample setup in a VM.

In man lvreduce it's recommended to first reduce the PV size. But pvresize is unable to shrink the volume, as it's 100% allocated.

```
pvresize --setphysicalvolumesize 700M /dev/vdb1 
/dev/vdb1: Requested size 700.00 MiB is less than real size 1022.00 MiB. Proceed?  [y/n]: y
  WARNING: /dev/vdb1: Pretending size is 1433600 not 2093056 sectors.
  /dev/vdb1: cannot resize to 174 extents as 255 are allocated.
  0 physical volume(s) resized or updated / 1 physical volume(s) not resized
```

It seems that I could manually (based on the sum of file sizes) calculate the space actually used in these drives and go against the recommendation: first shrink the LV to the desired amount of extents, and only then shrink the PVs. But that seems dangerous.

Also, can't find out how to read the correct amount of used space without opening it in file manager and summing files.
In this testing environment none of the storages are actually full, but I get the following anyway:

```
#pvdisplay 
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/vdd1
  VG Name               lt_t
  PV Size               340.00 MiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              84
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          84
  PV UUID               4vph5m-kReY-yukF-Crre-k2G9-c2UK-2pob7V
   
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/vdd2
  VG Name               lt_t
  PV Size               340.00 MiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              84
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          84
  PV UUID               LfE23C-rU4f-N404-5bBa-zstP-qHd8-SbwYru
   
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/vdd3
  VG Name               lt_t
  PV Size               340.00 MiB / not usable 4.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              84
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          84
  PV UUID               peDK1t-SZW6-VX0x-q0v1-7TUL-QZqq-unBeAV
   
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/vdb1
  VG Name               lv_s
  PV Size               1021.00 MiB / not usable 0   
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              255
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          255
  PV UUID               8sCpwh-2D5S-V5VP-v1N8-sgpd-dyra-xeqNXD
   
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/vdc1
  VG Name               lv_s
  PV Size               1022.00 MiB / not usable 2.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              255
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          255
  PV UUID               OF4fxd-f3eN-keTP-sf8p-ahVc-r35C-x7sb6l
```